How does this piece of code from an x86 bootloader that reads a FAT12 disk work?
x86 BIOS Interrupt 13,2
According to the image, the DL register has to contain a specific value in order to know what drive number to read from, however, in the following code (using intel syntax), we are instead moving the dl register into the value of the ebr_drive_number (that we defined above), instead of the other way around. How then is it able to function correctly, as I am able to read data from the disk.
ebr_drive_number: DB 0

; other code

main:
    MOV ax,0
    MOV ds,ax ;start address of data segment
    MOV es,ax ;start address of extended segment
    mov ss,ax ;start address of stack segments

    MOV sp,0x7C00
    
    MOV [ebr_drive_number],dl ;Drive number to read from <------------- HERE
    MOV ax, 1 ;LBA Index
    MOV cl, 1 ; sector number
    MOV bx, 0x7E00 ;pointer to a buffer
    CALL disk_read

    MOV si,os_boot_msg
    CALL print
    HLT 

when switching the order of the operation,
MOV dl,[ebr_drive_number]

which makes more sense in my head, as we are moving the value that we defined as ebr_drive_number into the dl register, which the interrupt needs, no data is read from the disk, but no build errors are present either.

Sound reasonable, but you're not doing int anywhere in this code - what does disk_read actually look like? If it's working and disk_read is just the BIOS call, the only logical explanation why it works must be that dl happens to already have the correct value.

ax = 1 so upper 8 bits are 0's, ah = 0 is reset disk system service, ah should be 2 if You want to read data.

The statement ebr_drive_number: DB 0 merely defines a single byte variable, initialised to zero. But the actual drive number is in the dl register, so needs to be moved there as you can see.

Bootloaders: "The DL register will contain the drive number that is being booted from."

@Nassau ah is set to 2 on a different procedure that actually reads the disk, I just included this very little snippet of code as I had a hard time wrapping my head around this particular operation

@RaymondChen ah, so the DL register is filled automatically with the drive number?

@OldBoy, makes sense, I thought that dl contained an uninitialized value, or that it may contain junk data but apparently it is automatically populated with the drive number that it's being booted from.

@500-InternalServerError disk_read is just the bios call, and yes, apprently the dl register is already populated with the drive number that is is being booted from, so that's why it works!

@MiEdCaLe BIOS bootstrap code do this. Like for example here: https://github.com/Gawlas/IBM-PC-BIOS/blob/e6cae33370fa7cd0568d72b785f682971edcc70c/IBM%20PC%20AT/AT%20BIOS%20V3/TEST6.ASM#L354 , instruction sub dx, dx sets dl to 0, fdd. If no errors, code jumps to @BOOT_LOCN, which is 0:7c00.
